# Can I use "any" in this example?

Tags: pronouns, questions

I know "any" is used only in plural (questions or negation) or for uncountable nouns OR if it expresses "whichever"/"every.
But what about this?

*Is there any document describing that?* //can I use it? I am not asking for one particular..I want to express that I need any document describing something

Comment: I have no idea where you got those rules for _any_. As Bidella points out, _any_ is not restricted to plural or uncountable nouns; it's a quantifier for nouns. Its usage is very complex because it has several senses, one of which is a Negative Polarity Item; but those rules are silly, and you should not trust any English text that contains them.

Comment: You can (grammatically) ask *"Is there any document describing that?"* - but in practice, even if only **one** would be sufficient, I think most native speakers would either say *"Are there any documents describing that?"*, or more likely *"Is there a document describing that?"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. In this case, "any" is being used to express "whichever", which I see you have included in your question already.